# Changing Image url & 3D model for AR.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, augmented-reality, ar.js

So I decided to add AR to a mobile app source code I have, but instead of changing my mobile app source code to do this I found a project online that would allow me to use the browser, AR.js.

Adding the test code works fine but when I try to add my own image url or 3D model it stops working, so I wanted to know if anyone can help by telling me how am I supposed to use the image url (which I think I am doing correctly) and the 3D model, the test url is very complex and the one I changed it to is a simple url from my website where I uploaded the new model.

Error is the url that loads stays stuck in "Loading, please wait" text. When it does manage to go pass it nothing happens.

Here is the original test source code.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- minimal loader shown until image descriptors are loaded -->
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
    <!-- we use cors proxy to avoid cross-origin problems -->
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/trex-image/trex"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
      <a-entity
        gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
        scale="5 5 5"
        position="50 150 0"
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-nft>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

And then my code I just updated the image url as well as the 3D model url.

```
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://mobileappstarter.com/AR/image/trees"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
      <a-entity
        gltf-model="https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://mobileappstarter.com/AR/3D/adamHead/adamHead.gltf"
        scale="5 5 5"
        position="50 50 50"
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-nft>
```

This is where I uploaded the file to open the camera to load the AR.
https://mobileappstarter.com/AR

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Francisco, what message do you receive in the browser console?

Comment: Thats just it, I don't get any message, just the browser with the camera opened.

Anyway I found a solution will post shortly for anyone who is facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

So doing a lot of research on this I found a simple workaround, wish I knew about this sooner.

AR.js has a simple to follow doc and git page but if by any chance your like me and still have issues there is a great toll online here https://ar-js-org.github.io/studio/ this nifty tool will help you create the marker and upload the media you wish to edit.

Once done just download source code or upload directly on github.

Hope this helps!